# i want to get the core data object based on object ID

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i have a Message entity when i fetch the particular item based on objectID

i use this to access but it's showing error

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.managedObjectContext.objectWithID(objectID
```

Comment: **What** error? It's important if you want an answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the object exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
do {
   let message = try managedObjectContext.objectWithID(objectID)
}catch let err{
  print(err)
}
```